# Error after project connected to firebase using Android Studio 2.2 Preview 3

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

when I tried to connect my project to firebase using  android studio 2.2 preview 3  automated tool  it shows this error

> Error:com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: Failed to crunch file %s into %s

this is build gradle  for app

```
  dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha3'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.0.0-beta1'
}
```

this is build.gradle for project

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio 2.2 preview 4  version fixed the issue.

http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio22preview4available

Comment: This issue is happening with the RC Version of 2.3 Android Studio also.

Answer (score -1):

Try using Android Studio 2.1

I had the same problem. Then I started using Android Studio 2.1. Works for me now

Answer (score -1):

This may happen when you change the project location

from - where you have created and coded the whole project

to - somewhere from where you are importing the project.